# Make individual async post requests

Tags: python

I want to write a simple function that makes a post request asynchronously. It would be great if it worked on 2.7 and 3.x, but i'm fine with it just working on 3.x. I'm having trouble finding something to do this though. All the examples i've found have been get requests, and it bundled many requests together. I just want:

```
def fun1(self, arg1, arg2, ...):
    ... #construct payload from args
    return requests.post("myurl", data=payload) #takes 10 seconds

def fun2(self, arg1, arg2, ...):
    ... #construct payload from args
    return requests.post("some other url", data=payload) #takes 20 seconds

def main():
   # do some stuff
   fun1("foo")
   # do some other stuff immediately 
   fun2("bar")
```

Is this actually possible? I just want to call fun1(), but not block the rest of the code waiting for it to complete.

Comment: If you only need it to work on 3.x you can use the asyncio library.

Comment: @Kat (or others) an answer showing how to use asyncio would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction) module to run a function with a pool of processes.

The introduction show this simple example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
     return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
     p = Pool(5)
     print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

will print to standard output ::

```
[1, 4, 9]
```

For your problem, you can write something like this:

```
p.map(requests.post, [("myurl", data...), ("myurl2", data), ...])
```

Comment: I can't just call all my requests at once though. I call fun1(), do some other work, THEN call fun2(). Can't call them at the same time.

Comment: It sounds like async methods are not an option then. Unless you are you trying to call "main" repeatedly in an async fashion.

Comment: `multiprocessing` spaw a fresh new interpreter (in your case five), to use multiple cpu core, wich is unecessary in this case. Using `threading` seems to me a much better idea.